# How to link to a glossary item (using package glossaries)

Tags: latex, pdflatex, glossaries

In my document i'm using the package glossaries to create a glossary. Everything works fine except that the is no link between the words in the text and the corresponding entry in my glossary (so you can click the word to be explained and get to the glossary entry).

The most important parts of my document:

```
%----Header----
...
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym,toc,style=altlist]{glossaries}

\usepackage[
colorlinks=true,
pdfborder=0 0 0,
pdfpagelabels,
plainpages=false,
linktocpage=false,
pdfcreator={LaTeX}]{hyperref}
...
%Glossary entries
\newglossaryentry{glos:twitter}{name=Twitter,
description={Mikroblogging-Service.}}

%----Main document----
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
This text is a normal glossary item: \gls{glos:twitter}.
This text should also link to the glossary item: \glslink{glos:twitter}{Link to Twitter} 
but there is no link
...
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

As you see i'm also using the package hyperref, but there seems to be no mechanism that automatically links words in the main text to the glossary.
I also tried to use \ref and \label, but this doesnt' work when the element that is referred is outside the main document (like my glossary is).
I'm using the makeglossaries-script coming from miktex (calling `makeglossaries main` on build), but this also doesn't give me a link.

Anyone knows a way to do that? Or maybe i should use another package than glossaries which supports a functionality like that?

I would also appreciate any working examples where this functionality works.

**EDIT:**

I just got a working minimal example where gls/glslink actually works. Seems like the linking of glossary items interfers with one of the packages im using in my document. Will have to try by adding my packages one by one to the example to see which package is the reason. The example:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
colorlinks=true,
pdfborder=0 0 0,
pdfpagelabels,
plainpages=false,
linktocpage=false,
pdfcreator={LaTeX}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym,toc,style=altlist,]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

%Glossary entries
\newglossaryentry{glos:twitter}{name=Twitter,
description={Mikroblogging-Service.}}

%----Main document----
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
Ein normales Wort aus dem Glossar: \gls{glos:twitter}.
Dieses Wort soll zum Glossar verlinkt werden: \glslink{glos:twitter}{Link to Twitter}
funktioniert aber nicht...
\clearpage
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the reason, but `hyperref` causes sometimes a bit weird problems if it is not loaded at the right moment. So you might try to load it *before* loading `glossaries`.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting. I always thought i have to load hyperref at the end to let it work correctly! Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I tried all combinations changing the order of glossaries and hyperref, still no links.
Any other hints? Is there a fully functional example on the net, where hyperlinking works correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As not mentioned in the extract of my latex-code, in my documentclass, the **draft** property was set to **true**. When removing this property or setting it to false, the gls/glslink work fine.